# Injectivity of a complex function with conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given is the function $$h: \mathbb{C} \setminus \{i\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}: z \rightarrow \frac{1}{\overline{z} + i}$$

How do I prove whether the function is injective or not? My approach is to set $h(z_1)=h(z_2)$, is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: For injectivity, you need to show that necessarily $f(z_1)=f(z_2) \implies z_1=z_2$. note that $$\frac{1}{\bar{z}+i}=\frac{z-i}{z \bar{z}+1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly by definition (fill in details):

$$h(z)=h(w)\iff\frac1{\overline z+i}=\frac1{\overline w+i}\iff\overline w+i=\overline z+i\iff \overline w=\overline z\iff w=z$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $h(z_1)=h(z_2)$

iff

$\overline{z_1}+i=\overline{z_2}+i$

iff

$\overline{z_1}=\overline{z_2}$.

Your turn !